# List and for mixing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script in which I'm trying to create .html file.
In this .html file there are 3 rows, left row, right row, center row.
Each of this rows to generate takes two arguments, one is title and other is description.

As an example we have a left row and right row elements stored in two lists, one is for title and another for desc:

```
rightRowTitle = ['title2','title2']
rightRowDesc = ['Desc','Desc2']
leftRowTitle = ['l1','l2']
leftRowDesc = ['l1','l2']
```

Here is an example of what I made:

```
rightRowTitle = ['Tytul','Tytul2']
rightRowDesc = ['Desc','Desc2']

leftRowTitle = ['l1','l2']
leftRowDesc = ['l1','l2']


for title, desc in zip(rightRowTitle, rightRowDesc):
    print(title,' - ', desc)
for title, desc in zip(leftRowTitle, leftRowDesc):
    print(title,' + ', desc)
```

the result:

```
Tytul  -  Desc
Tytul2  -  Desc2
l1  +  l1
l2  +  l2
```

Now, once I use functions to generate rows I would like to have such an result:

```
rightRowTitle
rightRowDesc
leftRowTitle
leftRowDesc
rightRowTitle2
rightRowDesc2
```

I would love it to mix between not to be static like now.

Comment: So you want a function to make all possible combos randomly, or just all combos of the rightRow 1 & 2 lists?

Comment: @Tony I want have it mix function a and function b, but function a takes different parameters than function b (from different lists)

Comment: FYI: rows are horizontal, columns are vertical. In Polish (I'm assuming that because of your name and "Tytul" in question) "row" is "wiersz" and "column" is "kolumna". Not trying to be a grammar nazi or smth, just wanna make it easier for you to ask a question that will be correctly understood.

Comment: @FilipMalczak Im aware, just bad explanation I guess, thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can usa `zip`twice.

```
rightRowTitle = ['Tytul','Tytul2']
rightRowDesc = ['Desc','Desc2']
leftRowTitle = ['l1','l2']
leftRowDesc = ['l1','l2']

[print(a) for a in zip(zip(rightRowTitle, rightRowDesc), zip(leftRowTitle, leftRowDesc))]
```

And you will get:

```
(('Tytul', 'Desc'), ('l1', 'l1'))
(('Tytul2', 'Desc2'), ('l2', 'l2'))
[None, None]
```

Look a bigger example:

```
rightRowTitle = ['Title1Right','Title2Right', 'Title3Right', 'Title4Right', 'Title5Right']
rightRowDesc = ['Desc1Right','Desc2Right', 'Desc3Right', 'Desc4Right', 'Desc5Right']
leftRowTitle = ['Title1Left','Title2Left', 'Title3Left', 'Title4Left', 'Title5Left']
leftRowDesc = ['Desc1Left','Desc2Left', 'Desc3Left', 'Desc4Left', 'Desc5Left']

[print(a) for a in zip(zip(rightRowTitle, rightRowDesc), zip(leftRowTitle, leftRowDesc))]
```

And you will get:

```
(('Title1Right', 'Desc1Right'), ('Title1Left', 'Desc1Left'))
(('Title2Right', 'Desc2Right'), ('Title2Left', 'Desc2Left'))
(('Title3Right', 'Desc3Right'), ('Title3Left', 'Desc3Left'))
(('Title4Right', 'Desc4Right'), ('Title4Left', 'Desc4Left'))
(('Title5Right', 'Desc5Right'), ('Title5Left', 'Desc5Left'))
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Now you only have to iterate through the result to get what you are looking for!  To call your function you can do something like this:

```
def myFun(title, description):
   print("Title: " + title + ". Desc: " + description)

def myFun2(title, description):
   print("TITLE: " + title + ". DESC: " + description)

pairs = [a for a in zip(zip(rightRowTitle, rightRowDesc), zip(leftRowTitle, leftRowDesc))]
pairs2 = [pair for pair in pairs]

for p in pairs2:
    myFun(p[0][0], p[0][1])
    myFun2(p[1][0], p[1][1])
```

And you will get something like this:

```
Title: Title1Right. Desc: Desc1Right
TITLE: Title1Left. DESC: Desc1Left
Title: Title2Right. Desc: Desc2Right
TITLE: Title2Left. DESC: Desc2Left
Title: Title3Right. Desc: Desc3Right
TITLE: Title3Left. DESC: Desc3Left
Title: Title4Right. Desc: Desc4Right
TITLE: Title4Left. DESC: Desc4Left
Title: Title5Right. Desc: Desc5Right
TITLE: Title5Left. DESC: Desc5Left
```

You only have to change `myFun` and `myFun2` with your function.

Comment: Let me try and inform you! @nestor

Comment: Its lovely but I still have 2 functions that I have somehow to use, thrue this this is rather not possible?
I need to use left_row(title,desc) and right_row(title,desc) somehow. Any idea how?

Comment: Thing is, I have 2 functions which should take 2 different lists into it. left_row for left_row list and right_row for right_row list, any chance you can change it for 2 different functions or perhaps even 3(cuz also center_row)

Comment: Look my answer now! @DamianBusz

Comment: This is working, however whenever I try to add 2 on left and 3 on right it just adds 2 on left and 2 on right, I guess cause it gets None on one right. Can we somehow secure this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store all the titles in a `list` and all the descriptions in another `list`. Shuffle them and make pairs one by one.

```
from random import shuffle

titles = ['Tytul','Tytul2', 'l1','l2']
descriptions = ['Desc','Desc2', 'l1','l2']
shuffle(titles)
shuffle(descriptions)
for t, d in zip(titles, descriptions):
    print(title + ' - ' + desc)
```

Sorry if this is not what you are looking for, but this is what I understand from your question.

You will get something like this:

```
// shuffled lists
titles = ['l2', 'Tytul2','Tytul', 'l1']
descriptions = ['Desc', 'l2','l1', 'Desc2']

// After the print
l2 - Desc
Tytul2 - l2
Tytul - l1
l1 - Desc2
```

@nestor

Here is a condition I have:

```
 if len(rightRowTitle) > len(leftRowTitle):
    for title, desc in zip(rightRowTitle, rightRowDesc):
        right_row(title, desc)
    for title, desc in zip(leftRowTitle, leftRowDesc):
        left_row(title, desc)
```

Problem is, this will not mix, it will just basicaly show me first left row and then right row result. I would like this to mix between.

Comment: Each function takes 2 parameters, functions have to mix if you know what I mean?

Comment: @DamianBusz I don't understand you... Can you give us an example of what are you looking for?

Comment: Edited post, please take a look in now

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the edit you did to my comment... Can you show me an example (not a code) of what are you looking for?

Comment: I get this now:
Function1
Function1
Function2
Functon2

I need to get this
Function1
Function2
Function1
Function2

Comment: I think I get it. I'm going to add a new answer! @DamianBusz